# How to change datastore options in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I created my application using "High Replication" option. Now I want to switch to "Master/Slave" option because I'm hitting my daily CPU quota.

It turns out High Replication uses "approximately three times the storage and CPU cost of Master/Slave"

Is there anyway I can do this without recreating my app? It's not in the Application Settings page.

Comment: Switching to the M/S datastore isn't a good idea - it's eventually going to be deprecated, and HR is much more robust.

Comment: And as far as cost is concerned, HRD and M/S are going to cost exactly the same when the new pricing scheme is rolled out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't - once you've chosen a particular type of datastore, that application is bound to it. The only way to change it is exactly the way you suggested - you'd have to create a new app with the Master / Slave datastore and port your data to it.

You may want to profile your app and optimize it to use less CPU, although in the general case that may be easier said than done.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the first answer to this question: [Have you expirienced DataStore downtime in AppEngine? What are the odds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467345/have-you-expirienced-datastore-downtime-in-appengine-what-are-the-odds)

As @mihai said:**I would recommend you to use HRD as Google said they will make M/S more expensive than HRD until the end of the year and even remove the M/S option as they are looking to "force" the businesses & developers to take advantage of all HRD goodies. The real reason is that maintaining a single type of infrastructure is cheaper than to maintain the both HRD and M/S so Google picks HRD. Source : Google I/O 2011**